# Retrofit Observables and Cancelling

Tags: android, retrofit

Can someone confirm if calling unSubscribe on the Observable is the right way to cancel a request?

Annoyingly, the Nexus 7 issues duplicate network requests and the first call needs to be thrown away as the calling Activity has been destroyed.

I got round this by checking the callback (my own) is not null before trying to use it.

Unsubscribing however, seems a better solution but could not find any information if this is the correct way to go.

I noticed that Retrofit would throw an internal error (InterruptedException) but that did not bubble up to my error callback - a good thing!

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, yes unsubscribing is a better way. If you haven't got [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) already installed as a dependency I recommend you do so, it makes managing `Observables` much easier. RxJava is also totally compatible with Retrofit.

Then you can unsubscribe from a `Subscription` in the `onDestroy` method as so:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
   if (bookingSubscription != null) {
       bookingSubscription.unsubscribe();
   }
   super.onDestroy();
}
```

Use of the `onDestroy` method will be useful when applied to your scenario too. You can unsubscribe from `Observables` in there.